# How to apply a function to each component of a variadic list and return a variadic list?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming, variadic-templates

The following didactic example illustrates my problem :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

template<class Function, class... Args>
double apply(Function f, Args... args)
{
    return f(args...);
}

template<class Function, class... Args>
double applybis(Function f, Args... args)
{
    return f(std::sin(args...));// <- How to apply a function to 
                                // each variadic parameter and 
                                // return a modified variadic list ?
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout<<apply(static_cast<double(*)(double)>(std::sin), 3.)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

How to "transform" a variadic list by applying a function to each component and return a modified variadic list ?
(Is there a way to write the applybis function without modifying its current signature ?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you go:

```
return f(std::sin(args)...);
```

That is, `...` should come after `(args)`.

It expands/unpacks to this form:

```
return f( std::sin(arg0), std::sin(arg1), ......, std::sin(argN) );
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I was expecting a huge program with a lot of helper classes using template metaprogramming... I didn't suspect that this syntax exists.

Comment: @Vincent: This is new in C++11. Before that, it would have been a lot more work.

Comment: @Nawaz : I have another problem. For some reason, I need to get a variadic list of types from a provided variadic list with the help of type_traits functions. The following : `class = typename std::result_of<std::sin(Args)>::type...` does not work. Is there any syntax available to do that ?

Comment: @Vincent : I suspect you want `decltype` rather than `std::result_of`.

Comment: Hum... maybe, but what would be the syntax with decltype ?

Comment: @Vincent : It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish – perhaps that warrants a new question.